# How to sum up all dynamic inputs in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get all the sum of these inputs? Sometime they have a value from the `database`, sometimes no value and needs to be inputted. I'm using jquery for this. 
Please see the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name=grade\\[\\]]').on('focus, keyup', function(){
    var points = $('input[name=grade\\[\\]]');

  var totals = points.get()
   .map(function(sel){
   return parseFloat(sel.value, 10);
  })
  .reduce(getSum, 0);


  if(points.length == 1){
   $('input[name=total]').val($(this).val());
  } else if(points.length > 1 && totals < 100){
   $('input[name=total]').val(totals);
  }
    
    
 });
  
  
  function getSum(total, value){
  return total + parseFloat(value, 10);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>

<input type="text" name="grade[]" ><br><br>
<input type="text" name="grade[]" ><br><br>
<input type="text" name="grade[]" ><br><br>
<input type="text" name="grade[]" ><br><br>
<input type="text" name="grade[]" ><br><br><br>

Total<br>
<input type="text" name="total" readonly>

</form>
```

Comment: Are you able to give each grade[] an individual id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `parseFloat()` returns `NaN` when the value can't be parsed as a number, and the result of adding up a list that includes some `NaN` values will be `NaN`. Which means your if/else that decides whether to display the total won't display it because `NaN < 100` is `false`.

Given that your inputs are empty to start with those items are parsed as `NaN`.

The simplest fix is to change this line in your `.map()` function:

```
        return parseFloat(sel.value, 10);
```

to be:

```
        return parseFloat(sel.value) || 0;
```

...where the `||` operator will return the left-hand operand if it is a truthy value, i.e., a number, not `NaN` or `0`, and otherwise return the right-hand operand `0`. That is, blank or otherwise non-numeric values will be treated as if they were `0`.

You don't need to call `parseFloat()` again in your `getSum()` function, because by then you already have numbers.

(Note also that `parseFloat()` doesn't take a second argument, you've mixed that up with `parseInt()`.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=grade\\[\\]]').on('focus, keyup', function() {
    var points = $('input[name=grade\\[\\]]');

    var totals = points.get()
      .map(function(sel) {
        return parseFloat(sel.value) || 0;    // <-- this is the line that changed
      })
      .reduce(getSum, 0);

    if (points.length == 1) {
      $('input[name=total]').val($(this).val());
    } else if (points.length > 1 && totals < 100) {
      $('input[name=total]').val(totals);
    }
  });

  function getSum(total, value) {
    return total + value;        // <-- no need for parseFloat() here
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="grade[]"> 
  <input type="text" name="grade[]"> 
  <input type="text" name="grade[]"> 
  <input type="text" name="grade[]"> 
  <input type="text" name="grade[]"><br><br><br> Total
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="total" readonly>
</form>
```

(I've removed most of the `<br>` elements just to avoid having to scroll down to see the total for demo purposes.)

Comment: Very Nice  answer! :)

Comment: One more thing. What if the `total` reached/greater than `100`? I want the last `<input>`  to back into its last `value`. For example `<input>1 = 20`, `<input>2 = 20`, `<input>3 = 20`, `<input>4 = 20`, `<input>5 = 20`, and then I change `<input>1` to `30`, I want it to have an `alert` and get the last value back into the `<input>1`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the value back automatically, because maybe the user would rather keep the value just entered and change one of the other inputs to compensate. As far as showing an alert, just add an if statement. By the way, note that a keyup event isn't enough because the user can modify the value via the Edit menu or with the mouse. Might want to use the `input` event instead.

Comment: That's great. But I want the to get the last value back into the `<input>` so he can choose other `value`.